# How to specify UUID in mongo $where clause

Tags: java, mongodb, where-clause, uuid, mongo-java

I have an object that was stored via mongo-java-driver. Object uses `java.util.UUID` for its `_id` field. Following is presentation of object via mongo shell:

```
> db.b.find()
{ "_id" : BinData(3,"zUOYY2AE8WZqigtb/Tqztw==") }
```

I have a requirement to process searching via `$where` clause. I use following code to do it:

```
Mongo m = new Mongo();
DBCollection coll = m.getDB("a").getCollection("b");
coll.save(new BasicDBObject("_id", UUID.randomUUID()));
// ??? - don't know what should be specified
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("$where", "this[\"_id\"] == " + ???);
coll.find(query).count()
```

The question is what should I specify instead of `???` to make it work?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My invesigation shown that only one way to do it is rewriting a query in object based way (I mean migration of $where clause part to BasicDBObject based query). In such case mongo-java-driver supports java.util.UUID without any additional effort.